# How to access web camera settings (like in Skype) using DotNet

Tags: c#

In my application I need to access my web Camera settings.
I saw that Skype calling to the camera's settings application.
Does anyone know how to do this?
I am using C#/WPF/dotNet 4 framework.

Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far? If you show us something we can give you start.

Answer (score 1):

```
[DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

[DllImport("avicap32.dll", EntryPoint = "capCreateCaptureWindowA")]
        public static extern int capCreateCaptureWindowA(string lpszWindowName, int dwStyle, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, int hwndParent, int nID);


        int mCapHwnd;
        private void btnAdvancedVideoSettings_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mCapHwnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA("WebCap", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            UIVideoSettingsControl.SendMessage(mCapHwnd, 1034, 0, 0);
            UIVideoSettingsControl.SendMessage(mCapHwnd, 1066, 0, 0);

        }

// VIDEOSOURCE  = 1066
// CONNECT = 1034
```