# How to access web camera settings (like Skype) C#

Tags: c#, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access web camera settings (like in Skype) using DotNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224748/how-to-access-web-camera-settings-like-in-skype-using-dotnet)

I found another question "How to access web camera settings (like in Skype) using DotNet" but it is very old with no answer. I have pretty much the same question.

I am developing a app using SkypeKit and to make it more complete to the user I would like to be able to tap into the webcam/audio/mic settings.

Is there an easy way using C# or skypekit ? & any advice.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to check out this library http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or a .Net wrapper for it such as [DirectShow.Net](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/).

Here are some projects that can help you going:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18511/Webcam-using-DirectShow-NET

http://www.barebonescoder.com/2012/01/finding-your-web-cam-with-c-directshow-net/

Comment: Thanks for the links . I did a bit of digging in forums and can confirm that DirectShow is whatthe desktop skype client uses.